# NSubstitute: Assert does not contain definition for Throws

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I am using the testing framework that comes with Visual Studio, along with NSubstitute to unit test a method that takes a system ID, and throws an exception if the system can't be found in the database...

```
public VRTSystem GetSystem(int systemID)
{
  VRTSystem system = VrtSystemsRepository.GetVRTSystemByID(systemID);
  if (system == null)
  {
    throw new Exception("System not found");
  }
  return system;
}
```

(In case this seems odd, there is a specific business case for this method that requires it to throw an exception, as returning a null system is not acceptable for its usage)

I want to write a test to check that an exception is thrown if the system doesn't exist. I currently have the following...

```
[TestMethod]
public void LicensingApplicationServiceBusinessLogic_GetSystem_SystemDoesntExist()
{
  var bll = new LicensingApplicationServiceBusinessLogic();
  try
  {
    VRTSystem systemReturned = bll.GetSystem(613);
    Assert.Fail("Should have thrown an exception, but didn't.);
  }
  catch () { }
}
```

By not mocking the repository, the system returned by `VrtSystemsRepository.GetVRTSystemByID()` will be null, and the exception thrown. Whilst this works, it looks wrong to me. I wouldn't have expected to need a try/catch block in a test.

The [NSubstitute docs](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/throwing-exceptions/) have an example that implies I should be able to test this as follows...

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetSystem_SystemDoesntExist()
{
  var bll = new LicensingApplicationServiceBusinessLogic();
  Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => bll.GetSystem(613));
}
```

However, if I try this in my test code, I get `Throws` highlighted in red, with the error message "*Assert does not contain definition for Throws*"

Now, I'm not actually sure that the sample on that page covers my scenario, as the test code specifies that the method under test throws an exception, which I don't really understand, as I thought the idea of testing was to leave the method under test alone, and test what happens under various scenarios. However, even without that, I don't understand why the `Assert.Throws` method doesn't exist.

Anyone any ideas?

**Edit:** DavidG pointed out that `Assert.Throws` is probably part of NUnit, not the MS framework, which would explain why it's not recognised. If so, is the way I'm currently testing the right way to do it?

Comment: Which test framework are you using? `Assert.Throws` is likely for NUnit.

Comment: @DavidG Ah, forgot to add that, sorry. I'm using the MS one that comes with VS. I'll update the question.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel as mentioned by DavidG The referenced documentation is using NUnit for assertions. If not using that framework you can use the [`ExpectedExceptionAttribute Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx)

Comment: Or use an extension method, like this http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/01/asserting-exceptions-in-mstest-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by DavidG The referenced documentation is using NUnit for assertions.

If not using that framework you can use the [`ExpectedExceptionAttribute Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx)

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(<<Your expected exception here>>))]
public void GetSystem_SystemDoesntExist() {
    var bll = new LicensingApplicationServiceBusinessLogic();
    bll.GetSystem(613);
}
```

which would fail if the expected exception is not thrown.

Comment: Even better, add an AssertThrows() method, which is much neater. See this MSDN page for info https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj159340.aspx#sec18